# Error passing parameters in play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, environment-variables

I have a play framework with one of the config file pointing to redis configuration.

```
redis.host="$IP_ADDR"
```

where IP_ADDR=XXX.XXX.XX.XX(in environmental variables)

The error message is

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: $IP_ADDR
```

Q1)Why is it pointing to $IP_ADDR when it should point XXX.XXX.XX.XX?

When I run in shell with `sh run.sh -Dredis.host="$IP_ADDR"` it is working fine.

Q2)How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the environment variable in brackets for the config library to reference it.

```
redis.host=${IP_ADDR}
```

Comment: Hi the problem again started it is now taking ${IP_ADDR). Any other way to work around this one?.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for accessing environment variable is wrong instead you should do

```
redis.host=${?IP_ADDR}
```

Here, the override field `redis.host=${?IP_ADDR}` simply vanishes if there’s no value for `IP_ADDR`, but if you set an environment variable `IP_ADDR` for example, it would be used.

Thanks to @Ryan for pointing me to right direction.

[**Play Docs**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ProductionConfiguration#Using-environment-variables)

Comment: `?` is used if you don't want to override a previous value if your environment variable is undefined.